# Convert SUM / CASE WHEN / GROUP BY SQL query into LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am having a VERY hard time converting my simple SQL query to LINQ...

```
SELECT Id
  ,Location
  ,SUM( CASE 
        WHEN TransactionType = 'Out' THEN [Quantity] * -1
        ELSE Quantity
        END) AS StockQuantity
FROM Transactions
WHERE Id = 123
GROUP BY Id, Location
```

here is my best WRONG attempt...

```
        var result = db.Transactions
            .Where(r => r.Id == 123)
            .GroupBy(r => r.Id, r => r.Location)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Location = r.Location,
                Quantity = sum(r.TransactionType == 2 ? r.Quantity * -1 : r.Quantity),

            });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your grouped values. Your query should be like:

```
var result = db.Transactions
         .Where(r => r.Id == 123)
         .GroupBy(r => new { r.Id, r.Location} )
         .Select(grp => new
         {
             Id = grp.Key.Id,
             Location = grp.Key.Location,
             Quantity = grp.Sum(t=> t.TransactionType == 2 ? t.Quantity * -1 : t.Quantity),

         });
```

I would also use a different variable name than `group` in projection (Select) since it is a contextual keywords (with query expression)

Comment: Should the `.GroupBy(...)` be `.GroupBy(r => new { r.Id, r.Location })` ?